# Implementing JQuery for search box in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to implement an expanding searchbox in wordpress. I have applied the HTML in my search-form.php and CSS in my style.css. However, I'm not sure how to apply the Jquery part. Is it as follows:-

```
add_action ('wp_footer','vr_search_head',1);
function vr_search_head() {
?>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var submitIcon = $('.searchbox-icon');
        var inputBox = $('.searchbox-input');
        var searchBox = $('.searchbox');
        var isOpen = false;
        submitIcon.click(function(){
            if(isOpen == false){
                searchBox.addClass('searchbox-open');
                inputBox.focus();
                isOpen = true;
            } else {
                searchBox.removeClass('searchbox-open');
                inputBox.focusout();
                isOpen = false;
            }
        });  
         submitIcon.mouseup(function(){
                return false;
            });
        searchBox.mouseup(function(){
                return false;
            });
        $(document).mouseup(function(){
                if(isOpen == true){
                    $('.searchbox-icon').css('display','block');
                    submitIcon.click();
                }
            });
    });
        function buttonUp(){
            var inputVal = $('.searchbox-input').val();
            inputVal = $.trim(inputVal).length;
            if( inputVal !== 0){
                $('.searchbox-icon').css('display','none');
            } else {
                $('.searchbox-input').val('');
                $('.searchbox-icon').css('display','block');
            }
        }
</script>

<?php 
}
```

search box from http://codepen.io/nikhil/pen/qcyGF/

I tried applying the above code in my child themes functions.php but it doesnt seem to work. On clicking search, the search box doesnt open.

Thanks

Comment: Is jQuery included/loaded? Is the syntax right?
Offtopic: You should include the jQuery in a seperate .js file.

Comment: Ya I guess so, cause I implemented a jquery scroll the same way and its working perfectly. You mean to incluse jquery in a seperate js file and load using wp enqueue script?

Comment: Unfortunately loadnig via wp enqueue is not working. I added the following to functions.php, and my wordpress website stopped working :(. So had to delete it.  function wptuts_scripts_load_cdn()
{
wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_load_cdn' );